# Notice: Undefined property: stdClass

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I have problem in my script with:

> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$job_details in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/curafides/home.php on line 1034

How can I fix this problem?
Example for job_title not sgh `<?php echo $jb_row->job_title?>`

And for job_details :

```
<?php

    if(strlen($jb_row->job_details) > 120) {
        echo substr($jb_row->job_details ,0 ,120)."...";
    } else {
        echo $jb_row->job_details;
    }

?>
```

Comment: What code creates $jb_row?

Comment: You provided almost nothing of your code context but only by the Error message I assume there is no correct instance of whatever object you're trying to work with at $jb_row, because it can't find any property named job_details in there.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like below:

```
if( isset($jb_row->job_details)  && strlen($jb_row->job_details) > 120){
   echo substr($jb_row->job_details ,0 ,120)."...";
}else{
  echo $jb_row->job_details;
 }
```

Comment: What if `$jb_row` IS AN OBJECT but has no **job_details** property?

Comment: Now if `$jb_row` is not object, it'll throw the same exception of undefined property. But this is bad verification anyway, because it should be tested before that point, at the line of instancing. We don't know how `$jb_row` is built due to lack of OP's info, so your answer is but a guess.